# Python code fragment - List

Tags: python, list

Given a `list L` with `at least 2 elements`, write a Python code fragment that swaps the second and the last
elements of the list:

My question - When they say a list with `at least 2 elements`, does that mean `l=[1,3]` ? and just wondering if thats what it means could someone care explain what they mean by `the second and last`?

For example even though it says `at least 2 elements` , what if I just want to use 2 elements, so would I just `swap` element `1 with 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that exact wording, a list with only two elements would yield the same list as before the "swapping".

```
l = [1,2,3]
l[1], l[-1] = l[-1], l[1] # l is now [1,3,2]

l = [1,2]
l[1], l[-1] = l[-1], l[1] # l is still [1,2]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it! (Not sure if I'm allowed to write this comment)

Answer (score 1):

A list with *at least 2 elements* verifies:

```
len(your_list) >= 2
```

The second and last elements are:

```
second_element = your_list[1]
last_element = your_list[-1]
```

So if you have a list with two elements, the second element **is** the last element, so swapping them will not change the list.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at a couple lists of different lengths:

#### A list of length two: `[1, 3]`

This list has *at least* 2 elements. The second element has a value of `3` and the last element is the same as the second element.

#### A list of length three: `[1, 3, 7]`

This list also has *at least* 2 elements. The second element has a value of `3` and the last element has a value of `7`.

#### A list of length ten: `[1, 7, 9, 5, 2, 11, 18, 21, 100, 9]`

This list also has *at least* 2 elements. The second element has a value of `7` and the last element has a value of `9`.

#### How do we swap elements of a list in python?

The simplest method is to use this idiom:

```
list[1], list[-1] = list[-1], list[1]
```

Alternatively, we can use a temporary:

```
temp = list[1]
list[1] = list[-1]
list[-1] = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

"At least two elements" means that you can say the following for your list `L` without worrying about an `IndexError` being raised:

- `L[0]  # First element is guaranteed to exist`
- `L[1]  # Second element is guaranteed to exist`
- `L[-1] # Last element is guaranteed to exit`
- `L[-2] # Next-to-last element is guaranteed to exist`

I *think* "second and last" refer to `L[1]` and `L[-1]` (unless it's a poorly worded ellipsis and they mean "second-to-last" and "last"—`L[-2]` and `L[-1]`).

Answer (score 0):

In function form:

```
def swap(l):
   assert len(l) >= 2 # check if length of l is at least 2
   l[1], l[-1] = l[-1], l[1] # swap first and last elements (in place)

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
swap(my_list)
print my_list # prints [4, 2, 3, 1]
swap([1]) # raises AssertationError
```